# to run window softwares on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: system-installation, window, playonlinux

I have already installed adobe photoshop 7.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04 by playonlinux using wine. installation is done without any error  butcan't run the photoshop.its showing only setup to run again.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this:

> Install wine (sudo apt-get install wine).
>
> Install virtual box, install windows inside the virtual bpx and start using windows applications there.

Comment: how to install virtual box

Comment: you can install virtualbox by following instructions from [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)... download linux hosts

Comment: i am unable to install anything from ubuntu sotware center , when i click anything to install install start but after it stop responding, not going finish n also unable to cancel it

Comment: i am not asking you to install from software centre. you can install from command line ... I have mentioned you about the link in previous comments